# Accordion inside Dropdown without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, accordion

I want to have an accordion inside my dropdown menu. However, when clicking on the accordion to open/close it, the entire dropdown collapses. Instead, I want the dropdown to remain open and the accordion to open/close freely.

[Check out a demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7pn9f85/3/)

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>

    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Test
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Test</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

There seem to be many similar questions out there but I cannot find the right solution. A lot of answers suggest using jQuery to solve this issue. Is there a way to do it without?

I believe using `data-boundary` or `data-parent` may be the way to do this but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst @Jake has given a valid answer, I found a "hack" of some sorts that lets this work without writing any additional JS.

Simply replace the accordion `div` with a `form` tag.

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>

    <form id="accordion">

        <div  id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Test
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Test</button>
          </div>
        </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why this works so I am unable to put the reason in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by adding an `onclick` event to the button that prevents the click from propagating down to the dropdown. Then you need to manually handle adding the relevant `collapse` or `collapse.show` classes to the accordion content in the `onclick` function like so:

```
function toggleAccordion(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var collapsable = document.getElementById('collapseOne');
  var classList = collapsable.classList;
  if(classList.contains('collapse')) {
    classList.replace('collapse', 'collapse.show');
  } else if (classList.contains('collapse.show')) {
    classList.replace('collapse.show', 'collapse');
  }
}
```

and the HTML with the click event added:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>

    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="toggleAccordion(event)">
              Collapsible Test
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Test</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I altered your JSFiddle to show a working solution and you can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ys1mLzqx/). Another note, I had to change the JS load type to `No wrap - bottom of <head/body>` to make this work.